# Create an IoT App for iPhone

Tags: mqtt, mobile-applications, eclipse-iot

After a year of testing, my IoT project come to an end.
It operates mainly on RPI0 using Python code, and ESP32 using MicroPython code, all connected using MQTT protocol running on RPI3.

Now i;m trying to build a basic App for my iPhone to control all those switches- today I'm using a very primitive MQTT App to type action and status command, and I'm looking for a more GUI kind of App.

Can anyone refer for a easy, preferably free ?

Comment: Why can't you wrap a GUI over MQTT? Or, am I missing something?

Comment: If you are not going to code it yourself, perhaps you should be asking for a ready made solution at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Not on my RPI, but an app on my iPhone.